# How to determine integral boundaries when calculating the two-dimensional common distribution function?

Tags: statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ have the joint probability density function given by $f(x,y)=2$, $0≤x≤1 , 0≤y≤1 , x+y≤1 ; 0$, elsewhere.

We want to determine the joint distribution function of $f$.

In this case of random variables, $x≤1$ , $y≤1$ and $x+y>1$, integral intervals are taken as follows:

$F(x,y)=P(X≤x,Y≤y)=\int_0^y\int_0^{1-y}2dsdt + \int_{1-y}^x\int_0^{1-s}2dtds$

I do not understand how the integral boundaries in this region are taken ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Professor, I have tried to find the $F(x,y)$ distribution by dividing the $xy−$ plane into 6 regions.

1)    $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\,$  $\alpha<0 \, , \ \beta<0$

2)     $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\,$  $(\alpha,\beta)\in(0,1)$ $\,$ $\,$ and $\,$$\,$ $\alpha+\beta<1$

3)  $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\,$  $\alpha+\beta>1$  $\,$ $\,$ and $\,$ $\,$   $(\alpha,\beta)\in(0,1)$

4) $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\beta\in(0,1)$ $\,$ $\,$ and $\,$ $\,$ $\alpha>1$

5) $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\alpha\in(0,1)$ $\,$ $\,$ and $\,$ $\,$ $\beta>1$

6)  $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\alpha,\beta>1$

Consequently, I have found the following joint distribution function according to these 6-regions:

1) $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ It's clear that $F(\alpha,\beta)=0$

2) $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $F(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{1-\beta}^{\alpha}\int_0^{1-x} 2dydx+\int_0^{1-\beta}\int_0^{\beta}2dydx= -\alpha^{2}-\beta^{2}+2\alpha+2\beta-1$

3) $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $F(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{1-\beta}^{\alpha}\int_{1-x}^{\beta} 2dydx= \alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}+2\alpha\beta-2(\alpha+\beta)$

4) $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $F(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^{\beta}\int_0^{1-\beta} 2dydx+\int_0^{\beta}\int_{1-\beta}^{1-y}2dxdy=-\beta^{2}+2\beta$

5) $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $F(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{1-\alpha}^1\int_0^{1-y} 2dxdy+\int_0^{1-\alpha}\int_0^{\alpha}2dxdy=-\alpha^{2}+2\alpha$

6) $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ $\,$ It's clear that $F(\alpha,\beta)=1$

Please tell me if there is anything wrong or missing ?

Answer (score 0):

$F(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^{\alpha \wedge 1}\int_0^{\beta \wedge (1-x) \wedge 1} 2dydx$ for $\alpha, \beta >0$. To compute the integral for $\alpha, \beta <1$  you have to have to split the outer integral into integrals over $
x \leq 1-\beta$ and $x >1-\beta$. I will leave the rest of the work to you.

Comment: Notation: $a \wedge b$ is the minimum of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Sorry Professor, thank you so much, but I don't understand anything from what you write. I have already drew the regions, but in this integral $F(x,y)=P(X≤x,Y≤y)=\int_0^y\int_0^{1-y}2dsdt + \int_{1-y}^x\int_0^{1-s}2dtds$  , what are the limits of integral ?

Comment: @sfera You have to divide the answer into a number of cases. For example if $\alpha, \beta \in (0,1)$ and $\alpha +\beta >1$ then we get $\int_{1-\beta}^{\alpha}\int_0^{1-x} 2ydydx+\int_0^{1-\beta}2ydydx$.

Comment: Is that  $\int_{1-\beta}^{\alpha}\int_0^{1-x} 2dydx+\int_0^{1-\beta}\int_0^{\beta}2dydx$   ???

Comment: @sfera Yes. Sorry that I missed $\int_0^{\beta}$ in my comment.